# Is it possible to apply the laravel code after the HTML code?

Tags: php, html, laravel, web

I've designed my site template with html and I'm newbie in laravel. I wrote template of my site and now I'm going to apply laravel code to it. Is it possible without changing the template of site, I apply laravel code?

Comment: welccome, read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're intending to do. You can easily integrate your current HTML within Laravel. Laravel comes with [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade), which is a templating language. You can echo various data from your Laravel backend to your views (your HTML in your case).

It's essentially how you'd normally convert a static HTML to dynamic with some PHP `<?php echo $username; ?>`, except, Blade provides a cleaner syntax, along with other features like extending layout files etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a result with controller in laravel and pass result to blade template to show it.
You can read it for more details :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views

now, you can use @php , @endphp for write php code in blade template directly. I recommend don't use this method, But if you had to and no choice, this method is exists.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#php